# Site is way too wide in screen-mode

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm a newbie trying to build a site with a responsive design. The design looks absolutely fine when it's scaled down below 500px for mobile view, but when scaling up, the site for some reason becomes way too wide and I get a horizontal scroll bar. I've gone through my code and I see no reason why it would do that since I have a fixed margin set for the main wrapper div.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

CSS

```
html body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}


.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  max-width: 70vw;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px

}

header {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#menuitem {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;

}
#menuitem a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article img {
  width: 56vw;
  height: 40vw;
  border: solid lightgrey 1px;
}
.article h2, p {
    width: 56vw;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

footer {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
footer a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {


section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px 20px;
}



section img {
  max-width: 20vw;
  max-height: 20vw;
}

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="food.css">
    <title> title | Home </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>title</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <div id="menuitem"><a href="#">recipes</a></div>
  <div id="menuitem"><a href="#">guides</a></div>
  <div id="menuitem"><a href="#">blog</a></div>
</nav>
<section>
  <div class="article">
    <img src="https://pickledplum.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/vegan-napa-cabbage-kimchi-2-1360.jpg" alt="Vegan kimchi">

    <h2>Vegan kimchi</h2>
    <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>

  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img src="https://www.weekendbakery.com/wp-content/uploads/sanfranciscosourdough.jpg" alt="Sourdough bread">
<h2>Classic sourdough bread</h2>
<p>Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx </p>
  </div>
  <div class="article">
    <img src="https://www.delectabilia.com/wp-content/uploads/vegetarian-red-miso-ramen.jpg" alt="">
<h2>Vegetarian miso ramen</h2>
<p> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx </p>
  </div>

</section>
<footer>
<div class="footersection">
<a href="#">recipes</a><br>
<a href="#">guides</a><br>
<a href="#">about</a><br>
<a href="#">contact</a><br>
</div>

</footer>


    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just do your research before asking questions here. You are making a lot of mistakes in the code, and it is not because you are a newbie, but because you don't go step by step. For example, I learned about media queries and grid, advanced CSS concepts, 2 months into coding, when I had everything well understood

Comment: @smunteanu. I don't see any apparent *mistakes* in OPs code. But whenever you are criticising please add some reasoning so that OP can comprehend what your criticism is about.

Comment: I meant that you first need to make a basic page working on desktop only, and only after that, make it responsive. I have never heard of an website working on mobile but not on desktop, and my explanation to this is that you didn't do your research correctly before getting into the media queries

Comment: @smuteanu I go step by step, if you were to dive into learning HTML and CSS these days you would know that most newer guides take a mobile-first approach since that seems more logical. I am not using code that I don't understand, I've actually taken everything very step by step and gradually built more advanced sites. As you'll notice, this site isn't even advanced, it's built with the sole puropse of understanding repsonsiveness better. Your reply is annoying because you don't seem to have an argument for the point you're trying to make.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `width: 20vw;`, use percentage like `width: 20%`. Your dummy text is way too long, so it doesn't break in the next line. Just google for lorem ipsum to get a more realistic dummy text :)

You can also flex the items, see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/41e9rm8o/ and this flex tutorial: https://sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seemed to do the trick. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My little suggestions:

- try mobile-first approach;
- use flexbox instead of grid (why `grid-template-columns: 1fr;`?);
- use more than one breakpoint (like Bootstrap, for example).